# QGIS Lyon MMQGIS geocode error

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I am trying to geocode a csv of 500 zip codes and keep getting this error -

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin/notfound.csv'  -

Can someone please help me get the MMQGIS plugin running again?

Comment: make sure you set the path to the notfound.csv as correct as possible, if not using the 'browse' dialogue to set it to a known path. The default is almost always wrong and causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put the output.csv into a different directory? If you work on a computer with more than one user sometimes the default (C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin/notfound.csv) doesn't work... Happened to me too at one point.